# How to make dynamically registered receive from outside of activity ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a class structure as below

```
public class Admin extends DeviceAdminReceiver 
{
 public static class PubSub extends Activity
 {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        messageIntentReceiver = new MQTTMessageReceiver();  
    IntentFilter intentCFilter = new IntentFilter(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_INTENT);  
    registerReceiver(messageIntentReceiver, intentCFilter); 
      }

      @Override
        protected void onDestroy()
        {
            unregisterReceiver(messageIntentReceiver);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

         public class MQTTMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  
    {  
        @Override   
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  
       {  
        Bundle notificationData = intent.getExtras();  
        String newTopic =                            notificationData.getString(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_TOPIC);  
        String newData  = notificationData.getString(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_MSG);
        Log.e("Received Message on",newTopic+"- "+newData);
           }
        }
 }
}
```

The receivers are dynamically registered and unregistered. The broadcast receiver works while PubSub activity stays on the screen. How to make it work from outside of activity?

I tried to do it in static way by registering in manifest.xml, but that dint work as MQTTMessageReceiver is a non static inner class. Cant able to instantiate the receiver runtime error I get.

I cant change the MQTTMessageReceiver class static as i need to access outer class members.

Comment: You can create MQTTMessageReceiver as a separate class and register it via AndroidManifest file

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should separate the Activity and the Receiver in different .java files. That way you should be able to register the receiver in the manifest.

Comment: make it a static class.